# Error when installing Google Cloud SDK on Ubuntu, how to fix?

Tags: google-cloud-sdk

I'm attempting to set up Google Cloud SDK CLI to manage some compute resources, and I'm just following a guide for this part. I ran this command and it installed lots of stuff successfully but ran into the problem below. Can anyone suggest a solution or how to debug?

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk                                   
[sudo] password for #######:                                                                                              
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                  
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [111 kB]                                                         
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [107 kB]                                                   
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [98.3 kB]                                              
Get:5 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk InRelease [6349 B]                                                
Ign:6 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk-focal InRelease                                                    
Err:7 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk-focal Release                                                        
404  Not Found [IP: 216.58.204.238 80]                                                                                
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [255 kB]                                       
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [7492 B]                                 
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [132 kB]                                  
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [4732 B]                            
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                           
E: The repository 'http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk-focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Did you follow step 1 listed here: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-apt-get ?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. I've seen something to suggest I should run an older version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue with Ubuntu 20. The solution is to install using snap.

```
snap install google-cloud-sdk --classic
```

Make sure you have `--classic` at the end, otherwise you'll get this error:

> error: This revision of snap "google-cloud-sdk" was published using classic confinement and thus
> may perform arbitrary system changes outside of the security sandbox that snaps are usually
> confined to, which may put your system at risk.
> If you understand and want to proceed, repeat the command including --classic.

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly what I needed :)

Comment: watch out tho, `This revision of snap "google-cloud-sdk" was published using classic confinement and thus may perform arbitrary system changes outside of the security sandbox that snaps are usually  confined to, which may put your system at risk.`

Comment: @jeremy_rutman what does that mean though? Am I not supposed to trust google?

Comment: imho you can trust google to do what's needed to maximize profit. Conceivably that includes respecting privacy , or not doing so but not getting caught.

Comment: This solved it for me, many thanks! +1

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem is in not updated documentation on Google. I used this for creating Docker image but I believe it solved normal installation too:

```
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 467B942D3A79BD29
 RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg

 RUN echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main" | \
     tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list && curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | \
     apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg  add - && apt-get update -y && apt-get install google-cloud-cli -y
```

keep attention on `http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main`. In Google website is `http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-cli main` so seems like name of package has been changed from `cloud-cli` to `cloud-sdk`.

Answer (score 1):

I get an error when use WSL, and i fix by run:

```
sudo snap  install google-cloud-sdk --classic
sudo snap  install google-cloud-cli --classic
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was to install the earlier 18.04 LTS version of Ubuntu (uninstalling 20.04). Having done this the Google Cloud Compute SDK install steps worked successfully.

I found a similar problem / solution described here:
https://forums.fast.ai/t/platform-gcp/27375/716

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to get `gcloud` on Ubuntu 20.04.3 with `apt`, at least not a recent version. I was tempted to get the latest through snap:

```
sudo snap install google-cloud-sdk --classic
```

But I can't think of a good reason for "*arbitrary system changes outside of the security sandbox*". By the way, there's the same warning for `node` so it's not that uncommon. Nonetheless, I prefer to run it in a container, which by the way, I also do for Node.js.

If you already run *docker* or *podman*, this could be another option. See an example shell session below, where I get version 360.0.0. I went for slim for now, because the default is around 1GB, but there are plenty of [tags](https://hub.docker.com/r/google/cloud-sdk/tags) to choose.

```
docker pull google/cloud-sdk:360.0.0-slim
# run a dummy tail so the container does not exit
docker run --name gcloud -d google/cloud-sdk:360.0.0-slim tail -f /dev/null
# now get a shell into it
docker exec -ti gcloud /bin/bash

root@ff77152a65ee:/# gcloud --version
Google Cloud SDK 360.0.0
alpha 2021.10.04
beta 2021.10.04
bq 2.0.71
core 2021.10.04
gsutil 5.3
```

Alternatively, for a container that will stop when you `exit` the shell:

```
docker run -ti google/cloud-sdk:360.0.0-slim /bin/bash
```

There's detailed documentation on the official [google cloud-sdk docker hub overview](https://hub.docker.com/r/google/cloud-sdk) page.

I have the following on my `~/.bashrc` for quick access into a "gcloud shell":

`alias gcloudshell='docker start gcloud && docker exec -ti gcloud /bin/bash'`

Note that it can be used multiple times, even if the container is already running.