# Stuck at Setting up google-cloud-sdk

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

`apt-get upgrade` is stuck at `Setting up google-cloud-sdk......` and it has been stuck for a while causing the server to be unresponsive. I couldn't terminate the process with `ctrl-c`.

I've never encountered this. What's the correct procedure to stop the process? I'm afraid if it will cause corruption.

There's ample disk space and memory.

Comment: can you have a look into this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62960276/15774176) and [doc](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install#deb) is it helpful?